# Not able to create SSH key pairs on OpenShift

Tags: ssh, openshift

I am not able to create an SSH key pair on OpenShift.com. I get the following error message

```
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/var/lib/openshift/$USER/.ssh/id_rsa): mytestkeys
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again: 
open mytestkeys failed: Permission denied.
Saving the key failed: mytestkeys.
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default you don't have permissions to change anything in the `~/.ssh` directory. However you can create a key-pair by going over to `~/app-root/data` and generating your key there. For example:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "test@redhat.com"
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/var/lib/openshift/540e021350044613d80000be/.ssh/id_rsa): ./id_rsa
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Your identification has been saved in ./id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in ./id_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
8c:d5:eb:3f:5c:86:07:d8:40:7e:aa:cc:6e:70:6a:42 test@redhat.com
The key's randomart image is:
+--[ RSA 2048]----+
|         ..      |
|         o.      |
|        . o+.    |
|       +  .+o    |
|      . S o  o   |
|    E .o.o  . +  |
|   .   ++ .. +   |
|    . o..  .o    |
|     o ..   ..   |
+-----------------+
```